# Unable to get and display data in another component

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I want to get my post by id and render them in a different component using angular routes, I have been able to get the id of each post and attached it to the url but I dont know where to go from here.

My service code:

```
getmaxPost(id : number): Observable<maxPost>{    
  const url = `${this.basePath}/${id}`;    
  return this.db.object<maxPost>(url)
}
```

My .ts code:

```
getmaxPost(): void {

  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  console.log("this is the", id);
  this.Service.getmaxPost(id).subscribe(fileUpload => this.fileUpload = fileUpload);
}
```

My imports for .ts:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { MaxPostServiceService } from '../max-post-service.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
```

My imports for service:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { maxPost } from '../max-post-model';
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to check if your console log of "this is the id" is getting printed properly. Next, I would suggest is to change your code inside subscribe TO:

```
subscribe(fileUpload => {
    console.log(fileUpload);
    this.fileUpload = fileUpload;
})
```

This should throw some light on where to look next in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define route in such way.

```
  {
    path: 'max/home/post-details/:id',
    component: PostDetailComponent,
  },
```

UPDATED:

regarding your configuration you should remove `/home/` from your URI

```
{
    path: 'max',
    component: MAXComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'window',
        component: WindowComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'post-details/:id', component: PostDetailsComponent,
      }
}
```

`post-details` is a child of `max` not `home`

So instead of  `max/home/post-details/91210655` that should be `max/post-details/91210655`

Or, change your route configuration to make `post-detaild` the child of `home`